# I keep getting "undefined" when I submit login form in Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I keep getting "undefined" when I submit login form in Codeigniter and I really cant find the problem, I have tried to set the encryption key even though I am not using it but that does not sort our the problem

This is my view

```
<!--loads the header-->
<?php $this->load->view('abt-header');?>
<!--this is the login page-->

<div data-role="page" id="Abt-login" data-add-back-btn="true">
    <div data-role="header" data-position="fixed">
        <h1>Login</h1>

    </div>
    <div data-role="content">

        <?php echo form_open('index.php/abovetheblues/login'); ?>
        <div data-role="fieldcontain">
            <p><?php echo validation_errors(); ?></p>

            <p>
                <label>Username: </label>
                <?php echo form_input('username', set_value('username') ); ?>

            </p>
            <p>
                <label>Password: </label>
                <?php echo form_password('password', set_value('password') ); ?>

            </p>

            <p>
                <?php echo form_submit('submit', 'Submit'); ?>
            </p>  

        </div> 
        <?php echo form_close(); ?>
        </div>

</div>
```

This is my function in the model

```
// checks username and password against the database
        function check_login() {
    $this->load->database();

    $this->db->where('email', $this->input->post('email'));
    $this->db->where('password', $this->input->post('password'));
    $q = $this->db->get('user');

    if ($q->num_rows() == 1) {
        return true;
    }
}
```

This is my code in the controller

```
 public function login() {

    $this->form_validation->set_rules('username', 'Username', 'trim|required|alpha_numeric|min_length[6]|max_length[12]|xss_clean');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('password', 'Password', 'trim|required|alpha_numeric|min_length[6]|max_length[6]|xss_clean');

    if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE) {

        // return main page if submitted form is invalid.

        $this->load->view('abt_login');

    } else {

         $this->load->model('abt_db');
    $q = $this->abt_db->check_login();


    if($q)
    {
        $data = array(
            'email'         => $this->input->post('email'),
            'password'      => $this->input->post('password'),
        );

        $this->session->set_userdata($data);
        redirect('index.php/abovetheblues/abt-abovetheblues');
    }
    else
    {
       redirect('index.php/abovetheblues/abt_selfhelp');
    }


    }
}
```

Comment: where u r getting that error?

Comment: it just says "undefined" on the interface and thats all

Answer (score 0):

Modify this line:

```
$user_id = $this->abt_db->$this->check_login($username, $password);
```

to this line

```
$user_id = $this->abt_db->check_login($username, $password);
```

*EDIT*

Also, your query would look better like this:

```
$q = $this->db->where(array('username' => $username, 'password' => $password))->get(user, 1);

if($q->num_rows == 1)
        {
            return true;
        }
```

**EDIT 2**

This is how I do it all the time:

MODEL:

```
function validate()
    {
        $this->db->where('email', $this->input->post('email'));
        $this->db->where('password', sha1($this->input->post('password')));
        $q = $this->db->get('users');

        if($q->num_rows == 1)
        {
            return true;
        }
    }
```

CONTROLLER:

```
function validate_credentials()
    {
        $this->load->model('site_m');
        $q = $this->site_m->validate();


        if($q)
        {
            $data = array(
                'email'         => $this->input->post('email'),
                'is_logged_in'  => true
            );

            $this->session->set_userdata($data);
            redirect('admin/dashboard');
        }
        else
        {
            $this->message->set('failure','Wrong email or password!');
            $this->index();
        }
    }
```

It works all the time. I think you are missing something in controller as well.

Comment: Sorry to ask but where do I use the variable $q?

Comment: Let me know if it works for you, if not, I'll paste my code that I use for every site and it always works. It's pretty much similar tho.

Comment: Thanks Matteo! I have tried the above code but it still says the same "undefined"

Comment: I posted a code how I do it all the time. I'm using email as username.

Comment: Hello Matteo! I have tried to use the code as above but it does not seem to do any validation

Comment: OH, sorry, I think you are talking about form validation, right? Or about user validation?

Comment: In your controller and in your model you have to replace any instance of 'email' with 'username'. In your view, the input is called username, but you are validating based on input email which doesn't exist. I posted my code with email, because I'm using email address as username. So just replace anywhere where you see email with username and it will work